# Copy directories in PHP, using system vs not simple recursive PHP code

Tags: php, directory, copy, php-5.5

I see there is not a built-in way to copy dirs in PHP. I saw [Copy entire contents of a directory to another using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050859/copy-entire-contents-of-a-directory-to-another-using-php/2050909#2050909) but I could not find any issue with `system('cp -R src dest')`.

Is there an issue with using the above `system` call? I assume the only "problem" is it will create one extra process for a fraction of a second. Right?

I will clarify, in this scenario, I do not develop an off-the-shelf product that has to be platform independent, nor the `src` or `dest` are coming from user input, they are 100% clean. Only problem I see (as was pointed out below) is error handling.

Comment: This seems an accepted way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2050909/980615

Comment: I saw that, I don't get why it is accepted and what is the advantage over one simple command line. That is my question, I guess.

Comment: Maybe because executing a command isn't platform independent?

Comment: hmmm...I do not write a shelf product. I have 100% control on the system I am deploying my code.

Comment: This thread has a nice discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7625302/980615

Answer (score 1):

- Assuming src and dest are not hardcoded you have to carefully escape input against shell injections
- This probably won't be cross platform compatible
- Error handling will become more difficult as you probably have to parse shell output/stderr

Edit:

When assuming src & dest are clean and cross platform compatibility won't be an issue, then only problem that still stands is error handling - [php copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) will explicitly return false in case of failure (for example incorrect filesystem permissions) and can be turned into custom recursive function.

Mayble Laravel FileSystem will help you - it is widely used and should be well tested: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php

In order to see how to get stderr for shell commands, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2320835/294696

Comment: Your points make sense in a general scenario. In my case the src/dest are generated from the code and from numerical ids that where cleaned and I do not work on a platform independent/shelf product. I will modify my question to spot those points